# C++ Code not working

Tags: c++

I'm new to StackExchange, but I have a simple class that seems to not return to the correct result when I run it.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int thisIsHowYouIfLikeABoss2(int, int);

int main()
{
     cout << "One." << endl;
     thisIsHowYouIfLikeABoss2(9, 9);
     cout << "Two." << endl;
     thisIsHowYouIfLikeABoss2(4, 9);
    return 0;
}

 int thisIsHowYouIfLikeABoss2 (int x, int y)
 {
    cout << "Welcome to the thisIsHowYouIfLikeABoss(), where I calculate if x = y easily." << endl;
    if (x = y)
    {
        cout << "X is Y." << endl;
    }
    if (x != y)
    {
        cout << "X is not Y" << endl;
    }
}
```

My compiler is GNU C++ Compiler for Ubuntu,if anyone was wondering.

Comment: `if (x = y)` should be  `if (x == y)`. You can also replace `if (x != y)` with `else` . If `x == y` is true it will capture that. A simple `else` will catch the case where it isn't equal

Comment: Rare is the question on SO that has a problem so generic and yet so frequent that, though there be undoubtedly *hundreds* of similar circumstances, there is little chance of finding a *general* duplicate. This would be one of them. Crank up your warnings and don't think you're done until they're *all* gone. And I suspect the title will yield no assistance whatsoever to the next person to stumble into this *identical* problem (unfortunately).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator, not the relational equality operator, which is `==`.

Change your code to this:

```
if (x == y)
{
    cout << "X is Y." << endl;
}
```

Protip: if you annotate your function's parameters with `const` then the compiler would have given you an error with that expression:

```
int thisIsHowYouIfLikeABoss2( const int x, const int y )
```

(Unlike in C# and Java, `const` in C++ does not mean the value is a compile-time fixed-value or literal, so you can use `const` with variables).

Comment: @James if you had the compiler set to show warnings it should have marked this statement as questionable.

Comment: @James I have amended my answer with a tip.